# Allocating a heap in memory and HEX addresses

Tags: hex

I'm a newbie to programming trying to understand the concept of memory allocation in computers. Say I have a HEX address of 0x0F342, and I want to allocate a heap of 1 kB with that as the lowest address. How would I add 1kB to 0x0F342? What does the HEX address represent exactly? Bytes, bits?

Edit: my question isn't more of me trying to allocate memory, as much as just trying to figure out HEX addresses themselves. I'm just wondering, say, if you have 0xF432, what is the address that is 1kB from that? If I have an element at 0xF432 that is 1 byte, what will the address of the next byte be? Thanks everyone!

Comment: What language are you using? It's not generally possible to specify the location for heap allocations, that's up to the heap manager.

Answer (score 0):

You'd get a better answer if you told us what platform you're working with.  I'm going to answer in C, because that's fairly easy, where this question makes no sense for Java, and explaining in assembler would be a lot harder.

---

Well, this is a good example of misunderstanding.  You should not be in the business of allocating memory -- that's best left to the run time libraries (malloc() in C, new in Java, etc).

The address they return might be something similar.  That's just a location in memory, like a street address is a location on a street to a house, but because there's millions of bytes available, they use a larger notation than "123".

To get this address, you would use a method like `malloc` (memory allocation), and tell it how much memory you want.  Let's say you want to store an integer number.  That's usually 2 bytes, but it might be 4 on some platforms, so we'll calculate it:

```
malloc( sizeof( int));
```

this might return an address like `0x0f342`

So, you might say "At address `0x0f342`, I want to store the value `4`". But that's cumbersome, and because the address is likely to change at various points in the execution cycle, we use a variable, called a pointer.

```
int *myInt;
myInt = malloc( sizeof(int));
*myInt = 4;
```

The `*` says "Treat the following variable as an address, and store the assigned value in this spot it points to" (thus, a pointer).  Now we don't even need to keep track of the specific address!

Unfortunately, there's no good way in C to keep track of the size of the allocated memory (usually), so you've got to do your own accounting for that aspect.

Comment: Ahh, thank you, that makes more sense now. I'm still fuzzy on HEX I guess. If I have an element's address as say 0xF432, and this element is 1 byte, where will the next address be? What is 0xF432 + 1 byte? Sorry if that makes absolutely no sense, I'm trying to understand the concept!

Comment: Hex is just numbers where a digit represents a number from 0-15 instead of 0-9.  That's where the A..F comes from ... A = 10, B=11, F=15.  `0x0F432 + 1 = 0x0F433`.

Comment: So the address is in terms of bytes. Thank you!

Comment: Usually, but not always.  If you're just learning and using an intel computer, then yes and ignore the "not always" part until you start working with weird stuff.